# Problems in training text on AdaGram.jl

Tags: machine-learning, julia, word2vec

I'm a newbie to Julia programming language. I am trying to install Adaptive Skip-gram (AdaGram) model on my machine. I'm facing the following problems. Before training a model we need the tokenized file and a dictionary file. Now my question is, what is the input that should be given for tokenize.sh and dictionary.sh. Please let me know the actual way in which the generation of output files happen and also the extension of the same.

This is the website link I'm referring to : https://github.com/sbos/AdaGram.jl .
This is exactly similar to https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package provides a few shell scripts to pre-process the data and fit the model:
you have to call them from the shell, i.e., outside Julia.

```
# Install the package
julia -e 'Pkg.clone("https://github.com/sbos/AdaGram.jl.git")'
julia -e 'Pkg.build("AdaGram")'

# Download some text
wget http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/100.txt.utf-8

# Tokenize the text, and count the words
~/.julia/v0.3/AdaGram/utils/tokenize.sh 100.txt.utf-8 text.txt
~/.julia/v0.3/AdaGram/utils/dictionary.sh text.txt dictionary.txt

# Train the model
~/.julia/v0.3/AdaGram/train.sh text.txt dictionary.txt model
```

You can then use the model, from Julia:

```
using AdaGram
vm, dict = load_model("model");
expected_pi(vm, dict.word2id["hamlet"])
nearest_neighbors(vm, dict, "hamlet", 1, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have a challenge here. I'm not able to figure out where the model is being placed after creation. I'm not able to find it anywhere across my system. When I restart julia interpreter after training the model, I get the error : "Opening file model: No such file or directory."

Comment: It should be in the directory in which you launched `train.sh`, 
probably the same directory that contains the initial corpus, the tokenized corpus, and the dictionary.
You can use an absolute path when creating and using it.